# how to include an element ONLY when it's not rendered with Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Our Angular application can be served both via Spring Boot and via "ng serve" (mostly for development purposes). In the first case, it's `index.html` is rendered with Thymeleaf, in the latter it's not.

And I need to include a `<script>`, which will have `src` as url A in the first case (a prod script, when served via Thymeleaf) and url B (dev link) in the second case..

Can't think of way to do it. I can do

```
<script th:src='url-A'></script>
<script src='url-B'></script>
```

which is OK for the 'dev' deployment (no Thymeleaf), but when it's served with Thymeleaf, both elements will be rendered and thus processed by browser, which I would want to avoid..

I wonder if there's any construction that would let me have *something* in the template, that is a safe and valid HTML when it's not processed by Thymeleaf; AND is rendered to nil (empty string) when it is ?

Comment: seems like 'th:unless' might do the trick; need to test..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple easy ways to accomplish this.  The easiest is simply including a `th:src` and a `src`.  Thymeleaf will overwrite the static src when it's rendered in SpringBoot (and it will be left alone when served via `ng serv`).

```
<script src="url-B" th:src="url-A"></script>
```

You can also use the `th:remove` attribute.

```
<script th:src="url-A"></script>
<script src="url-B" th:remove="all"></script>
```

Comment: cool! I came already to provide my own "answer" (I confirmed that th:unless="false" also does the trick). but I like the first solution better